# output which has first and last letter as vowel(a,e,i,o,u)

Tags: sql, oracle

I want output like. I have to print those city which has first and last character as vowel.

```
ashoke
eureka
onkar
okkko
uae
eau
```

to this I have written below query. any effective way to do the same.

```
select distinct city from station where city like 'a%%a' or
city like 'a%%e' or
city like 'a%%i' or
city like 'a%%o' or
city like 'a%%u' or;
 city like 'e%%a' or
city like 'e%%e' or
city like 'e%%i' or
city like 'e%%o' or
city like 'e%%u' or
 city like 'i%%a' or
city like 'i%%e' or
city like 'i%%i' or
city like 'i%%o' or
city like 'i%%u' or
 city like 'o%%a' or
city like 'o%%e' or
city like 'o%%i' or
city like 'o%%o' or
city like 'o%%u' or
 city like 'u%%a' or
city like 'u%%e' or
city like 'u%%i' or
city like 'u%%o' or
city like 'u%%u' ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all the city names are all lower-case letters, you could do something like this:

```
select city
from   station
where  substr(city,  1, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
  and  substr(city, -1, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

`substr(city, 1, 1)` takes the substring of `city` starting at position 1 and of length 1 (meaning, just the first letter). `substr(city, -1, 1)` is very similar, just the position is different: `-1` means first letter from the **end** of the string - so this will give you the last letter of the city name.

If `city` may have both upper and lower case letters, in the `WHERE` clause use `lower(city)` instead of `city`.

**EDIT**: By popular request, here is how the same can be done with regular expressions. There is no point in using a regular expression approach here though; the standard string functions (like SUBSTR) are almost certain to be much faster than anything based on regular expressions.

```
....
where regexp_like(city, '^(a|e|i|o|u).*(a|e|i|o|u)$', 'i')
```

`(a|e|i|o|u)` means exactly one of those characters. `^` means anchor at the beginning of the string, and similarly `$` at the end of the string. Strictly speaking, this requires the city name to be at least two letters long; if one-letter city names are possible, this can be modified easily. (The SUBSTR approach would require no changes.)

The last argument, `'i'`, makes the regexp matching case insensitive (just in case that is needed).

Comment: thank you very much. I am getting correct output. Can it be done using regexp?

Comment: @OnkarTiwari - yes, it can, but why? The regexp solution is guaranteed to be substantially slower than the "standard" string functions approach.

Comment: I understand...but could you please tell me the regex query pls

Comment: @OnkarTiwari - I posted it already; 16 minutes before you asked. Please check again.

Comment: I'd prefer `'^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'`, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple alternative answer to the question

```
select city
from   station
where  left(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
  and  right(city, 1) in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u')
```

Comment: The question is for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct city from station where city like '%[a,e,i,o,u]' and city like '[a,e,i,o,u]%'
```

Comment: The question is for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LOWER(LEFT (CITY,1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u') 
AND LOWER(RIGHT (CITY,1)) IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What's the purpose of your answer relative to the query in the question?